# Can you derive the limit definition of an integral with an Euler's method construction?

Tags: integration, riemann-integration, eulers-method

If you were to try to approximate the value of $f(x+3\Delta x)$, you could use Euler's method to make 3 linear approximations.

$$f(x + \Delta x) \approx f(x) +\frac{df}{dx}(x)*\Delta x $$

$$f(x + 2\Delta x) \approx f(x+\Delta x) +\frac{df}{dx}(x+\Delta x)*\Delta x $$

$$f(x + 3\Delta x) \approx f(x+2\Delta x) +\frac{df}{dx}(x+2\Delta x)*\Delta x $$

From this method, you can get that

$$f(x + n \Delta x) \approx f(x) + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{df}{dx}(x+i\Delta x) \Delta x$$

Where given n-linear approximations, the width $\Delta x$ is calculated as $\frac{b-a}{n}$.

If you take an infinite limit, it's equivilant to the Riemann integral limit, and you get

$$f(x) + \int \frac{df}{dx} dx$$

$$\int f'(x) dx + C$$

Is there a name for the limit definition of an integral, where the construction appears like Euler's method for approximation, until you evaluate it with a limit as you would do for a Riemann approximation that then evaluated with a limit gives an exact answer?

Thanks!

Comment: The thing is, we tend to resort to things like Euler’s method when the integral/antiderivative *can’t* be nicely evaluated, for whatever reason

Comment: I am not saying this is Euler's method, because Euler's method is for approximation. What I am asking is, is there a name for the limit definition of an integral, where the construction appears like Euler's method for approximation, until you evaluate it with a limit as you would a Riemann integral. It's basically a different approach that gives you the exact same limit, but I don't know if it has it's own name, or if it's also called a Riemann integral limit.